# How can I get the person with same case no in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table called `CASE_PERSON`.The DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE CASE_PERSON
(
  ID VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
  p_id VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL,
  id_card VARCHAR2(18) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL,
  p_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  case_no VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  case_name VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
 )
```

And some DML

```
insert into CASE_PERSON(ID, P_ID, ID_CARD, P_NAME, CASE_NO, CASE_NAME)
values ('001', '123', '123-123123', 'tom', 'c-001', 'case-one');

insert into CASE_PERSON(ID, P_ID, ID_CARD, P_NAME, CASE_NO, CASE_NAME)
values ('002', '234', '123-123234', 'rose', 'c-001', 'case-one');

insert into CASE_PERSON(ID, P_ID, ID_CARD, P_NAME, CASE_NO, CASE_NAME)
values ('003', '345', '123-123345', 'jack', 'c-001', 'case-one');

insert into CASE_PERSON(ID, P_ID, ID_CARD, P_NAME, CASE_NO, CASE_NAME)
values ('005', '555', '123-123555', 'roman', 'c-002', 'case-two');

insert into CASE_PERSON(ID, P_ID, ID_CARD, P_NAME, CASE_NO, CASE_NAME)
values ('006', '666', '123-123666', 'jim', 'c-002', 'case-two');
```

The table is built from a `Person` table and `case` table. The prefix with p is from `PERSON` and case is from `CASE`.First I get all the idcard from `PERSON` and query from `CASE_PERSON` to find the person with same case who are matched the given idcard.

Now I want to get the result called 'person with same case'. The output should be the following format:

```
id   p_id   id_card    case_no case_name  same_case_id_card same_case_p_name
 1    123  123-123123   c-001  case-one     123-123234           rose
 2    123  123-123123   c-001  case-one     123-123345           jack
 3    555  123-123555   c-002  case-two     123-123666           jim
```

How can I do the query?

Comment: Your sample data is not sufficient to clearly describe all possible scenarios. Do you want multiple rows for each matched case? Why does it only apply for p_id = 123 in your sample? what will happen to others, say case_no of rose also equals that of jack and vice versa. Show us the complete result expected for this sample data and explain clearly the meaning of *"get the result called 'person with same case'"*

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes,I got this thread a bit confused. I edited my question, please check it.If you need more specify detail, just tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the case details from the first person, crossed with the person details of non first persons:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY case_no ORDER BY p_id) as rown FROM case_person
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY two.p_id) as id,  
  one.p_id,
  one.id_card,
  one.case_no,
  one.case_name,
  two.id_card as same_case_id_card,
  two.case_name as same_case_p_name
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rown = 1) one
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rown > 1) two
  ON one.case_no = two.case_no
```

Comment: I tested your sql but this was not what I want. Sorry for the first post I just got it wrong to describe the scene. I edited it, you can have a check.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I’ve edited my post. The first sql did provide what you asked for, it’s just that what you asked for wasn’t what you wanted..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm afraid the sql is not what I desired. When I ran your sql it did give some results but it looked the result have some duplicate rows.

Comment: Fixed a bug with the extra rows

Comment: Thanks. Your solution helps a lot.

Comment: May I ask for one more time if I want to display all possible records? The above is displaying accomplice of  'tom' and 'roman'. But if I want 'person with same case' of  'rose' ,'jack'  and maybe more person, cane we use one sql to accomplish the goal?

Comment: I picked on tom and roman because they were omitted from your desired results and they share a fact that they are the lowest numbered people on their respective cases. If you are writing a system that will show "rose" who else she shares a case with, that's a bit different.. make the `one` and `two` subqueries have `where` clauses of `p_name = 'rose'` and `p_name <> 'rose'` respectively. If you do this, there's no real need for the CTE, you can ditch it and just put case_person in. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cae46/10

Answer (score 0):

I think the query your looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM case a, case b 
WHERE a.case_no = b.case_no;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your query produces 9 rows and 12 columns, none of which look like the rows the OP is looking for, sorry. Also, consider not using this old style join syntax in favour of newer named join styles like INNER, LEFT OUTER etc